# Pixeles trasparentes en un poligono con tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas

Tengo un problema,estoy haciendo una aplicación en tkinter,y quiero agregar un modo noche,y necesito crear un rectángulo que cubra toda la pantalla de un color negro transparente,para que así sea mas cómodo de ver por la noche.

Se que para crear un rectángulo hay que hacer lo siguiente.

```
canvas.create_rectangule(0,0,100,100,fill="black")
```

para crear un rectángulo hay muchos argumentos que desconozco,y lo mas posible es que eso existe pero lo desconozco.

alguien me pudiera decir como hacerlo.

Muchas gracias a quien responda

:)

Comment: O sea, queres que todos los widgets estén cubiertos por "una tela negra transparente"???

Comment: es que hago una aplicacion de dibujo,el canvas del centro no le puedo cambiar el color poque si no,caudno uso la funcion borrar(que no es mas que un color blanco)y por ejemplo lo pongo de color gris,el blanco queda expuesto y la unica solucion es esa @DanteS.

Comment: Mil disculpas, no te llegue a entender del todo. Entiendo que queres dibujar un rectangulo transparente negro. Pero eso solo puede hacerse dentro de un canvas y NO funciona con widgets (como botones) sin importar si estan o no en el canvas. Ademas, seria necesario un modulo de terceros.

Comment: lo quiero hacer dentro de un canvas,no en un boton,la verdad no soy muy fan de agregar imagenes a un label siempre me gusto mas el canvas porque acepta transparencia con la imagenes. @DanteS.

Comment: Espera, repasemos. Queres cubrir tooooda tu aplicacion (canvas, botones, entrys, etc) con un rectangulo negro transparente?

Comment: ademas a loa widget les puedo cambiar el color y nada ba a suceder pero al canvas no puedo hacerle eso.por que si no el blanco se ve expuesto.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140685/discussion-between-dante-s-and-maykol-gonzales-cueti).

Comment: nooooo solo el canvas.@DanteS.

Comment: La palabra es "así", no "haci".

Answer (score 0):

Lamentablemente, no existe una forma de lograr una transparencia parcial con un poligono. Tkinter no se destaca en el tema de la transparencia.
Lo que si, eso es posible usando imagenes. Por lo que existe un "hack" que sería crear una imagen de un solo color y transparencia parcial. Si queremos, podemos regenerar la imagen cada vez que el canvas cambia de tamaño.

No te sientas mal por creer que había una forma más facil y directa, por que la verdad, opino que debería de haberla. Además, hiciste bien en preguntarte por una forma más directa, ya que primero hay que tender a ver que materiales de construcción tenés, y si te falta algo, recién ahí comprás algo nuevo.

Pero volviendo al tema, esta imagen también será un item del canvas. Por lo que si cambias el orden de dibujado de los items o creas uno nuevo luego de la "tela negra", este se dibujará sobre dicho negro transparente.
Para solucionar eso, tendrás que llamar a una función llamada tag_raise(id del item) que pondrá el item al final de la lista de items, siendo dibujado a lo ultimo.

Implementé todo esto en una clase derivada de tkinter.Canvas llamada NightCanvas, ojalá te sirva (usa una librería de terceros llamada Pillow):

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class NightCanvas(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # creo un ovalo
        self.create_oval(100, 100, 200, 200, fill="red")

        # creo la "tela" y guardo su id en un atributo.
        self.tela = self.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw")

        # el evento <Configure> se llama cada vez que el widget cambia de tamaño.
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.on_change_size)

    def raise_tela(self):
        # Llama a esta función para que la tela quede al final
        # de la lista de items
        self.tag_raise(self.tela)

    def on_change_size(self, event):
        self.make_tela(event.width, event.height)

    def make_tela(self, width, height):
        self.tela_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.new("RGBA", (width, height), (0,0,0,100)))
        self.itemconfig(self.tela, image=self.tela_img)

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = NightCanvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

> Esta tecnica no funciona con los items window, ya que en realidad estos crean una especie de "agujero" en el canvas para mostrarse. No importa lo que hagas, no se puede dibujar nada sobre un item window. Si necesitas una solución a esto, haz otra pregunta, hay un hack un poco desagradable para lograr eso.